# How to Serve the code on multiple EC2 instances via ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

The EC2 machines are running behind the ELB with the same AMI Image.

My requirement is, currently there are 5 EC2 instances are running behind the ELB this is my Min count in Auto-scaling Group and I also associated Elastic IP with them so its easy to serving code on them via Ansible, But when traffic Goes up Auto-scaling add more machines behind the same ELB, Its very Headache to add newly added machine public IP manually in Ansible Host.

How can I get all the machines IP  to my Ansible host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the classic use of dynamic inventory. Ansible docs even call out this specific use case :)

They also provide a working example. Check this [link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#inventory-script-example-aws-ec2)